# generated: true not working in loopback 4

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, loopback, loopback4

I am new to Loopback 4 and I made a model then data-source to MYSQL then repository then the controller (REST), then I visited `http://127.0.0.1:3000/explorer/#/TodoController` and went to POST section and then tried to insert some data I got:

> Unhandled error in POST /todos: 500 Error: ER_NO_DEFAULT_FOR_FIELD: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value.

I searched the internet and found `generated: true` to auto increment the `id` field then I run `npm run migrate` and again inserted data in the POST section but again got the same error.
I changed the `A.I` (auto-increment) field of `id` in MYSQL-DB to true then it inserted the data successfully.

All I want to make the `id` field auto-increment, how can I do that.
I tried `generated: true` in `todo.model.ts` under `id` property but not working.

```
@property({
  type: 'number',
  id: true,
  generated: true,
})
id?: number;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone is messing up with this issue just move `generated: true` before `id: true` as:

```
@property({
  type: 'number',
  generated: true,
  id: true,
})
id?: number;
```

A pretty fix :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the way as @ok answered but it's not working for me.

I am using MySQL db and I **need to set a default value to 0**. Then the issue is ok. werid.